# Python WMI shows stale data

Tags: python, wmi

Using [Python's WMI package](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/contents.html) to mount a [MSFT_Partition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830524(v=vs.85).aspx) which previously didn't have a drive letter can be done as below:

```
import wmi
c=wmi.WMI(namespace=r'Microsoft/Windows/Storage')
partition=c.MSFT_Partition()[0] # Picking sensibly outside of scope of question
partition.AddAccessPath(None,True) # Use AssignDriveLetter
# This works so far and the mounted drive can be seen

# But now the Python object is outdated:
print('%c:'%partition.DriveLetter)
# Still prints '\x00:'
```

So what's the correct way to ask the Python WMI module to refresh this stale value?

Comment: What do you expect as the output?

Comment: @m170897017 The letter that was automatically assigned to the drive - if I look in diskpart, or browse the local machine it's there, but it doesn't show in Python until destroying and recreating the object.